# Remove Facebook search cache

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

I was blocked by an ex but they still appear first in the search when I type the first letter of their name. If I click them it will go to their profile for second flash to a not available screen.

I don't even want to be able to search for them or see their profile for a second. I can clear my search history but that only clears what shows when I click the search without typing anything.

It's like the results are cached somewhere server side. How do I completely remove all my search history, cache, etc.?

Comment: The search results are certainly cached on the server side. You're seeing an index, not the live data. I expect the index will catch up in a day or two. You might try blocking them yourself.

Comment: I don't believe you can block someone that has blocked you =/ but cool I will check in a few days

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your activity log, click More, and then select Search from the left column
2. Click next to the search entry you want to remove
3. Click Delete

[reference](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-clear-my-Facebook-account-cache-memory)

Comment: This does not work for what I want. It clears out what happens when I click the search bar and recent searches appear. But even with all that cleared if I type in the one letter I can still see a person that has blocked me, and they still appear first no matter what because I obviously searched for them a lot in the past.

Answer (score -2):

You can see the option *Clear search results* last in the list of search results.